# How to set MySQL parameter multiple values in variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to assign multiple values in a variable and execute a query using it. For example below:

```
SET @ledger = "'Cash','Special Offer'";

SELECT `_ledger` FROM `acc_ledger` WHERE `_ledger` IN(@ledger);
```

But this doesn't work as planned. Is there a way to define multiple values in a variable? If yes, how? If no, can I have a suggestion on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Do you really want to do this only in MySQL or are you using some kind of "frontend" language like php?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple values with comma separated and then split those variables int table and perform a join

*create function to split comma separated parameter*

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SPLIT_STR` $$
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(id_list VARCHAR(500), delimeter VARCHAR(10), position INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_list, delimeter, position),
                             LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_list, delimeter, position - 1)) + 1),
                   delimeter, '');
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

*call SPLIT_STR function from query*

```
SET @ledger = "Cash,Special Offer";

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selected_types` (type varchar(50));

#inserting splitted values to temp table

simple_loop: LOOP
    SET indx=indx+1;
    SET str=SPLIT_STR(x_id_list,',',indx);
    IF str='' THEN
        LEAVE simple_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO selected_types VALUES(str);
END LOOP simple_loop;

#filter with temp table

SELECT `_ledger` FROM 
`acc_ledger` led
inner join selected_types tmp on tmp.type = led._ledger;
```